# How to set localhost as endpoint of a topic subscription - Amazon sns service

Tags: amazon-web-services, go

I need to implement amazon sns service in my localhost to test an Go Application but when i tried to set my localhost as Topic subscription's  Endpoint it shows Error:

```
Not authorized to subscribe internal endpoints (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AuthorizationError; Request ID: 14bc8224-4b0d-5b9a-a61c-d24122fdf703)
```

is it Possible?I am new to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you mean an HTTP/S endpoint? SNS is run by Amazon, so localhost points to their server. You will need to make your endpoint accessible from the internet. Please see Step 1 here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.html#SendMessageToHttp.subscribe

Answer (score 4):

Now, this is really an old post. But I tried something similar recently using the ngrok service. https://ngrok.com/

This service assigns a temporary endpoint to your localhost and this endpoint is completely resolvable from the public internet.

For example if you are running an HTTP server at port 8080, you can start the ngrok with the command "ngrok HTTP 8080" (of course this requires that ngrok desktop binary is download and set in the path variable). But once you run this command, every traffic which is coming to the temporary ngrok endpoint is redirected to your local service.

Something like this:

http://c5fdddc8.ngrok.io -> http://localhost:8080

You can subscribe to the ngrok endpoint in the AWS sns topic and it will redirect the HTTP request to the service running in your localhost.